# What is the status of adding mouse Click-Lock accessibility feature in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, accessibility

I'm checking in to see what the status is of enabling the mouse Click-Lock feature on Ubuntu's latest 18.04 OS. I recall that it was advertised to be available with the 16.04 release but the developers backed out. I'm hoping that this crucial feature can be enabled somehow in 18.04, but I still don't see how to enable it. This has been a standard Accessibility feature in Windows for a decade or more. It is the one feature that has prevented me from using Ubuntu as one of my laptop OSes. The alternative accessibility dwell feature is not very functional for me. I'll stick to Windows before going that route. I've tried numerous other hacks, like xinput, but never got a good  functional click-lock behavior there. This really needs to be a core component, easily enabled, as it is in Windows. I've been fighting, trying to get this added to Ubuntu for many years without success. I would hope that the importance of good accessibility features on par with Windows would have been given the light it deserves by now, but still waiting...

Thanks,
David

Comment: Same here, I want this feature too.